# ¿Cómo ordenar una lista de strings teniendo en cuenta la segunda letra y usando función lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, ordenamiento

Un ejercicio me pide ordenar una lista de strings `ex_lst = ['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']`, teniendo en cuenta la segunda letra de cada string, y usando una función lambda.

Primero para saber si estaba ordenando usando la segunda letra hice esto:

```
def second_letter(x):
    return sorted([(i)[1] for i in x])


ex_lst = ['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']
print(second_letter(ex_lst))
```

Que me genera el output:

```
['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'y']
```

Que son las segundas letras de cada string.

Luego esto fue lo que intenté hacer:

```
ex_lst = ['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']

lambda_sort = sorted(ex_lst, key=lambda k: ([(k)[1] for k in ex_lst]))
print(lambda_sort)
```

Pero no resultó bien, ya me que genera este output:

```
['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']
```

Lo que no se bien cómo hacer es que tenga el cuenta la segunda letra para ordenarlas.

Si pueden ayudarme, gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `sorted` tiene un argumento opcional `key` donde se pasa una función que recibe como argumento un elemento del iterable a ordenar. Esta función retorna un valor que se usa para ordenarlo respecto a otros elementos.

La función es normalmente un lambda.

En este caso queremos que la comparación se haga por el segundo caracter del string, por lo que el lamba será uno que reciba una palabra y retorne el segundo caracter.

```
lambda palabra: palabra[1]
```

El código completo es:

```
ex_lst = ['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']
lista = sorted(ex_lst, key=lambda palabra: palabra[1])
print(lista)
```

produce:

```
['dance', 'zebra', 'hi', 'how are you', 'apple', 'bye']
```